# The app is starting a blank screen before starting the splash screen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I'm starting my app with splash screen for 3 seconds but the app is starting with a white blank screen first and then going to splash screen in android studio i want the first thing appear when starting app is the splash screen here is AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.loginregister">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"/>
    </application>
```

---

SplashActivity.java code

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Handler;


    public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

        Handler handler;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            handler=new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            },3000);

        }
    }
```

---

activity_splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.android.loginregister.SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/start_activity"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

and when removed splash screen and make it start with the LoginActivity it also start with white blank screen first and goes to login activity

Comment: Emulator or real device?  Does it work on a real device without a debugger attached?  Does it work if you go directly to the login screen?

Comment: Please check that instant run is enabled in your system or not ? if its enabled then its issue because of instant run.

Comment: it is in both emulator and real device i have put these lines to my app theme <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> ... and it works fine thank for your help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Can you post a small video? Because all apps open with a blank white screen (for a very short time) and then the first activity begins. Try opening chrome or your play store app and you will see it.

EDIT: There is a workaround for this. In your apptheme, add the following lines:

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

Comment: it finally works for me .. i have been searching two days for this .. thank you very much for your help it was very specific and helpful